# Improving performance of searching slice of structs for value

Tags: arrays, go, hashmap

How can I optimize the code below for searching an array of maps for a specific key-value (and then return the other key-values)?

```
type userMap struct {
    JiraUsername    string
    CHProjectID int
    CHID        string
}

func main() {
    var userMaps []userMap

    userMaps = append(userMaps, userMap{
        JiraUsername: "ted",
        CHProjectID: 81,
        CHID: "23jk3f32jl3323",
    })

    fmt.Println(GetUserInfo(userMaps, "ted"))
}

func GetUserInfo(userMaps []userMap, jiraUsername string) (CHProjectID int, CHID string) {
    for _, u := range userMaps {
        if u.JiraUsername == jiraUsername {
            return u.CHProjectID, u.CHID
        }
    }
    return 0, ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is reasonable, but it's not array of map, it's slice of struct. The efficient way would be

```
type userMap struct {
    JiraUsername string
    CHProjectID  int
    CHID         string
}
type UsersMap map[string]userMap

func main() {
    userMaps := make(UsersMap)
    userMaps["ted"] = userMap{
        JiraUsername: "ted",
        CHProjectID:  81,
        CHID:         "23jk3f32jl3323",
    }

    fmt.Println(GetUserInfo(userMaps, "ted"))
}

func GetUserInfo(userMaps UsersMap, jiraUsername string) (CHProjectID int, CHID string) {
    if u, ok := userMaps[jiraUsername]; ok {
        return u.CHProjectID, u.CHID
    }
    return 0, ""
}
```

This doesn't require loop and has O(1) complexity.